# ZonedDateTime.parse could not parse at index 2

Tags: java

After looking at similar questions and solutions on here I have not been capable of successfully parse a date. I am trying to parse the date like so below. But whenever it gets called it throws the error

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-08-05
>   23:59:00America/Chicago' could not be parsed at index 2

Here is the code I am talking about. Any insight or tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-05 23:59:00America/Chicago", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mmVV"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is completely wrong. It doesn't match the format you're trying to parse.

The following pattern would work: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssVV"`.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ZonedDateTime parse = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-05 23:59:00America/Chicago", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssVV"));
    System.out.println(parse);
}
```

This code prints `2019-08-05T23:59-05:00[America/Chicago]`

Explanation:

- `yyyy` - year, in 4 digits
- `MM` - month, in 2 digits
- `dd` - day, in 2 digits
- `HH` - hour, 2 digits in 24 hour format
- `mm` - minutes, 2 digits
- `ss` - seconds, 2 digits
- `VV` - timezone id

The code you posted fails at index 2 because it expects day-of-month value in 2 digits (`dd`) for which it sees `20` and then, at index 2, it expects a forward slash (`/`) which you don't have.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response! I appreciate it. As soon as it allows me to, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @JacobTStaggs You're welcome. I've also edited the answer to explain why you got the `could not parse at index 2` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Theoretically what you have posted should have worked, also.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(string);
```

Comment: that pattern cannot possibly work with the date OP provided